# MATLAB correlation loop excluding specific column

Tags: matlab, indexing, correlation

I'm trying to write code to perform a correlation on some data, but for each iteration to exclude one specific column from the calculation. A is a *1000x60x5* matrix and B is a *1000x1* vector.
At the moment I have

```
out(60,5)= zeros;  % preallocate for loop output


for ques=1:size(A,2) 
    for rep=1:size(A,3)
        out(ques,rep) = corr(A(:,[(1:ques-1):(ques+1:end)],rep),B(:),...
        'rows','pairwise','Type','Spearman');
    end    
end
```

Is there a way I can specify (instead of `[(1:ques-1):(ques+1:end)]`) to exclude the `ques` column from the calculation?

Comment: Do you mean `[(1:ques-1):(ques+1:end)]` or `[(1:ques-1),(ques+1:end)]`?

Comment: the former. Since A is 3-dimensional and the dimensions are designated as A(:,Z,rep) where Z represents a range `1:end`, but missing out `ques`. If that makes sense? I'm probably not explaining it very well.

Comment: I think you mean the latter. Compare these in Matlab: `[(1:19):(21:60)]` and `[(1:19),(21:60)]`, the former is simple `1:21`, the latter is a concatenation of `1:19` and `21:60` which is what I think you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I actually wanted to do was this

```
out= NaN(1000,60,5); % preallocate for speed
for part = 1:size(A,1) % loop for dim 1
    for ques = 1:size(A,2) % loop for dim 2
        for rep = 1:size(A,3) % loop for dim 3
            cols = 1:size(A,2);
            cols(ques)=[]; 
            out(part,ques,rep) = nanmean(A(part,cols,rep));   % exclusive means         
        end
    end
end

out=nanmean(out,3); % collapse third dimension

final = corr(out,B,'rows','pairwise','type','Spearman'); % do the correlation
```

using the means of each row of `A` excluding each column in turn, collapsing across the third dimension, then correlating with `B`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the way you are handling your 3rd dimension is as you have intended. I think what you've done is fine but here is an alternative that won't error when `ques == 1` or `ques == size(A,2)` like yours will. On the downside, it might actually be slower than your method, I haven't tested it.

```
out(59,60,5)= zeros;  % preallocate for loop output


for ques=1:size(A,2) 
    for rep=1:size(A,3)
        cols = 1:size(A,2);
        cols(ques) = [];
        out(:,ques,rep) = corr(A(:, cols, rep),B,...
        'rows','pairwise','Type','Spearman');
    end    
end
```

Comment: Hmm... Unfortunately I now get the dreaded `??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.` error...

Comment: @8eastFromThe3ast Hmmm... at what line are you getting the error? And what are the values of each of the subscripts at that point?

Comment: It errors at the function line (`out...`). I'm away from my work computer at the moment, but will check subscript values when I get the chance

Comment: @8eastFromThe3ast doesn't make sense to me, are you sure of the dimensions of `A` and `out`? Maybe declare `out` as `out(size(A,2),size(A,3))= zeros;` to make certain you're being consistent?

Comment: yes, definitely sure of the dimensions... Even with what you suggested.

Comment: @8eastFromThe3ast OK I understand now, `corr(A(:, cols, rep),B,...` returns `59` values and you're trying to stuff them into element. You would need to make out 3 dimensions. I'll edit the answer

Comment: huh... but I don't need it to return 59 values... should be one value per iteration...

Comment: @8eastFromThe3ast But that's not how `corr` works, you are giving it 59 columns in A and 1 column in B so it gives the correlation of each of those 59 columns with B. Hence 59 values. If you only want 1, you need to redefine the problem

Comment: Ye, i think I've phrased it wrong. I'll go and fiddle with the inputs, see if I can get it right this time. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Managed to sort myself out in the end, answered my own question with what I actually needed to do. Thanks for the advice about `cols(ques)=[]`.